# problems installing latest ruby version

Tags: ruby, debian

I need some help here with RVM and installing the latest version of rails on a debian server. please note im not a linux programmer so you'll have to spell out everything for me.

basically i'm trying to upgrade to the newest version of ruby. I'm trying to install that on a debian server that I connect to via VPN. I'm trying to use RVM so far, but when i run the `RVM install 1.9.3` from my debian bash prompt it says there are no binary available for that version, then proceeds to try and grab the source from online which fails (probably due to the firewall). basically when it grabs the source folder from online, it grabs a corrupted hunk of junk. I tried downloading the source package myself and if i click the link on the ruby site it blocks it. If i use wget it appears to download it, but the md5 doesnt match and i cant untar it the thing. it says gzip: stdin: the file is not in gzip format.

So! I neeeedddsss to help. What I was thinkin was getting the binary rubies for 1.9.3.. but I'm unsure how really.. I downloaded the tar.gz file on my windows and used winSCP to move it over, and then I can use untar the thing fine.. and then i have an unzipped folder that is the source from the site.. but im unsure where to go from there.. apt-get install doesnt seem to recognize the tar.gz or the untarred folder.. i tried rvm mount and specifying the path to ruby.exe file (ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby) but then it says unrecognized command line argument and i should see the usage..

Any advice out there? (preferably without 3rd party programs or stuff other the RVM)

thanks

Comment: You tried to install an exe on a debian ?!

Comment: If RVM is not working, did you try instructions given at  http://wiki.debian.org/Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading back on my questions, I remember now, it WAS the firewall. The firewall where I was working at the time didn't allow me to download ruby source properly. It was downloading, but not actual source, corrupted source. So, I did it at home and it worked fine.

Just thought I'd pop this in here in case anyone ever finds it when problems installing ruby.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're a novice, I suggest skipping RVM unless you know you need it.

Debian has great way to install Ruby and make it available for all of the system users:

```
 sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
```

You will use the root password to install it this way.

To verify it worked:

```
 ruby -v
```

That should print out something like this:

```
 ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: def tried that first. nope. but then just now i found the read me file in the unzipped ruby folder. told me how to compile the ruby. maybe once i can do that i can point the RVM mount at it.. i'll try your way again though just in case.

Comment: it worked... i don't know how... i think running make install from inside the unzipped ruby folder is what did it.. regardless of the fact that im almost positive your answer didnt work, (maybe because of the firewall?) thanks anyways

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. It's a good idea to find out how to get the apt-get installation working, because it will help with many dependencies and keep the security up to date.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to install ruby using rvm: Just execute the commands in the same sequence..

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl git-core ruby
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

--give the password for sqlserver or you can just press enter.

```
$ gem install rails
```

You have ROR setup now!